# MySQL cancelled import - orphaned data in ibdata file

Tags: linux, mysql, import

I was importing a database dump - almost 1GB worth:

```
mysql -uroot -ppassword < mysqldump.sql
```

When I received warnings that the hard drive was almost full. I panicked and Ctrl-Ced the import. Twice.

Looking at my DB I can see that the import was canceled. However when I look in `/var/lib/mysql/` I can see `ibdata1` is still too big - I guess it still has all the imported data in it. It's about twice the size it should be for the data available in the DB.

I ran `mysqlcheck -optimize -A` but if anything it made the `ibdata1` file larger.

How can I clear this orphaned data out? I have about 100MB left on the hard drive ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in MySQL: [1341](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=1341). It's been going on for 8 years now.
You might want to try a workaround, [posted on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456159/how-to-shrink-purge-ibdata1-file-in-mysql/3456885#3456885):

That `ibdata1` isn't shrinking is a particularly annoying feature of MySQL. The `ibdata1` file can´t actually be shrunk unless you delete all databases, remove the files and reload a dump.

But you can configure MySQL so that each table, including its indexes, is stored as a separate file. In that way `ibdata1` will not grow as large.

It was a while ago I did this. However, to setup your server to use separate files for each table you need to change `my.cnf` in order to enable this:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_file_per_table=1
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/multiple-tablespaces.html

As you want to reclaim the space from `ibdata1` you actually have to delete the file:

1. Do a `mysqldump` of all databases, procedures, triggers etc
2. Drop all databases except the mysql-db
3. Stop mysql
4. Delete `ibdata1` and `ib_log` files
5. Start mysql
6. Restore from dump

When you start MySQL in step 5 the `ibdata1` and `ib-log` files will be recreated.

Now you're fit to go. When you create a new database for analysis, the tables will be located in separate `ibd*` files, not in `ibdata1`. As you usually drop the database soon after, the `ibd*` files will be deleted.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/drop-database.html

Or, if you want to keep the database running whili you do this, you could try this:

Enable the innodb_file_per_table option without shutting down the database. The idea is:

- Configure your original database as master. Unless your database is already using
  binlogs for security, this is the only step that will require restarting MySQL.
- Make a backup of the original database using Xtrabackup.
- Restore the backup and run a second instance of MySQL.
- Run mysqldump on the second instance.
- Stop the second instance, but do not delete it yet.
- Create a new database and start the third instance of MySQL with the enabled option
  innodb_file_per_table.
- Restore the dump by feeding it into the third instance of MySQL.
- Configure the third instance as slave and run the replication.
- When the initial replication finishes and the slave catches up with the master,
  reconfigure your clients to use the new instance.
- That's it. You can stop the first instance now and delete it.

[A detailed article can be found here.](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/380876-howto-reconfigure-mysql-to-use-innodbfilepertable-with-zero-downtime)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I'll give this a try when I get home.

Comment: I have the same steps when I answered this question a year ago : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927690/howto-clean-a-mysql-innodb-storage-engine/4056261#4056261. Notwithstanding, your answer is totally correct. It should be accepted. It gets a +1 for answering this particular question first.

Comment: I also like your plug for XtraBackup in case anything goes wrong.

Comment: Hey Bart, I just read your StackOverflow link. Someone answered it a month before I did. Anyway, cleaning up ibdata1 is a necessary evil. At the very least, it should never have to be revisited.

Comment: Thank you. That seems to have fixed the problem, a tick for you sir. Does splitting up the tables into files speed up the db at all? Why the big log files, what does that do?

Comment: Hey. It sure does speed up things. The big log files are common in DB-world. It's to be able to revert a state of a DB.